# Is possible Clone a property in GA4 (Google Analytics 4) and use it with a similar website?

Tags: google-analytics, migration, google-analytics-4

My company has 6 sites and 6 properties in Google Analytics (GA). We recently hired an external agency to migrate and adjust one property for one of the sites from Google Universal Analytics to GA4. I am a  web developer, but I have been tasked with replicating these changes for the other 5 properties and 5 sites.

Since the properties per site are very similar, I am wondering if it is possible to clone or find a way to replicate this project for the other 5. **We use Google Tag Manager**, and I am curious if using the GA4 Setup Assistant is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make the same process this year, and there isn't a complicated task
The Google Analytics has a "step-to-step" tutorial showing how to do.

In short, you just need to copy this code (With your unique ID)
[code GTA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8XNV.png)
To the head property of your site

```
<head>
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-{{YOUR TAG}}"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-{{YOUR TAG}}');
</script>
</head>
```

You will need to see in this project if has one unique header or multiples
If u are using wordpress, is easier, you can download some plugin who does this automatically, you just need to copy the GTA Tag

U can get your GTA Tag in the menu "web" of your GTA Property

Comment: Thanks , there was GA4 involved , I nailed it in the end

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts, GTM and GA4.

For GTM, if you have multiple GTM accounts, you can simply export the tags from the first site and import to the other sites. Just make sure you update the Stream ID.

For GA4, if you have multiple GA4 properties, there is no easy way to do this. You have to re-create each properties. However, if you want to maintain a single GA4 property, you can actually create multiple Streams but it's not advisable because there would be 5 Web streams.